# Что правильней использовать в качестве первичного ключа id или user_name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Создаю таблицу для хранения пользователей. Логин пользователя естественно уникальный. Вопрос: что использовать в качестве первичного ключа суррогатный ключ `id` или же использовать логин. 
База данных MS SQL Server.
В бд будет еще много таблиц и практически все они будут ссылаться на первичный ключ из таблицы пользователей.

Comment: `id` с `auto_increment`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте ID.
Возможно случится ситуация в которой логин придется поменять. В таких ситуациях используя ИД будет проще работать.
Старайтесь всегда использовать ИД, если это возможно.