# Суррогатный ключ в таблице с одним полем

Tags: sql

Разбираюсь с базами данных, и часто вижу такой пример:

**Таблица User:**
UserId
Login
...
RoleId

**Таблица Role:**
ID
Name

Таблица **User** связана внешним ключом с таблицей **Role**.

Если имя роли уникальное, то нормально ли, если таблица **Role** будет без суррогатного ключа ID, а вместо поля RoleId в таблице **User** будет поле RoleName, ссылающееся на это уникальное имя?

По производительности будут различаться эти варианты?

В поисках ответа я нашел [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493727/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-id-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-user-name), но не объясняется, почему же проще работать с ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что Вам необходимо ознакомиться с нормализацией отношений в реляционных базах данных (к примеру). Дело в том, что если мы храним внешний ключ на связанную таблицу, то это как правило таблица, в которой как минимум два столбца, так как хранение ссылки в виде значения на само значение совсем не целесообразно.

Благодаря правильно спроектированному первичному ключу мы обеспечиваем целостность данных, то есть не будет двух записей в таблице с одинаковым идентификатором, чего не скажешь про имена (рано или поздно возникнет ситуация, когда имена совпадут, *как классический пример с ФИО - Иванов Иван Иванович, когда появляется второй такой*).

Да, изменение имени не приведет к нарушению целостности. А вот идентификатор ты не поменяешь. Явные значения в столбец идентификаторов таблицы можно вставить только через [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188059.aspx), причем необходимо обладать достаточными правами для применения этой операции. Идентификаторы меняются крайне редко (вообще не меняются), а значение, хранящееся в значении иногда меняется.

Также более удобно работать с числами, чем со строками во время выборки данных. Проще связывать данные в нескольких таблицах. Да и запросы будут быстрее, чем нежели работа со строками.

С целью повышения производительности поиска данных используют индексы. Индекс на основе чисел будет быстрее, чем аналогичный строковый.

Comment: Речь о ролях, а не об именах.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в вопросе, в таблице роль - поле имя. Посмотрите внимательно.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, по производительности теперь понятно.  
А вот насчет "значение, хранящееся в значении иногда меняется" - 
если это происходит достаточно редко, то можно использовать cascade update.  
"хранение ссылки в виде значения на само значение совсем не целесообразно" - если в таблице **Role** есть другие столбцы, то мы с помощью этого уникального RoleName ссылаемся и на другие столбцы.

Comment: @user3887377, `хранение ссылки в виде значения на само значение совсем не целесообразно` - это как минимум глупо.Зачем таблица с одним столбцом, в котором только идентификатор-значение?По поводу уникального RoleName - если это неизменяемый первичный ключ и есть другие столбцы - то в этом может быть смысл, ведь никто не запрещает. Но в таком случае Вы теряете память за счет того, что храните строку дважды. А если бы был идентификатор в виде числа, то два числа и строка занимали бы меньше места. Просто принято в качестве идентификатора использовать число или Guid - если записей будет очень много

Answer (score 1):

Смотря о какой производительности вы ведете речь.
Если вы говорите о полной выборке из таблицы USER то конечно если там сразу будет прописано RoleName - то будет быстрей выбрать из одной таблицы чем из двух. Но если вопрос коснется выборки всех пользователей уже определенной роли то построить индекс по ID роли будет куда менее затратно чем строить индекс по Name. При этом при апдейте роли "дешевле" проапдейтить одну запись в Role чем кучу записей в USER.

Comment: Имена ролей обычно не меняются...

Comment: да ну :) они могут меняться, у них могут меняться свойства итд итп